# Ext:net : Property grid bind it to store

Tags: ext.net

is there anyway to bind propertgrid to the store.
I find a sample here ,is this the only way to bind data to propertgrid?I wanna bind data like as bind the gridview thank you

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void Populate(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyGridParameter p = new PropertyGridParameter();
        p.Name = "dynamic";
        p.Value = "property";
        p.Editor.Add(new ComboBox());

        this.PropertyGrid1.SetSource(new PropertyGridParameterCollection() { p }, true);
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET v2 Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <ext:Button runat="server" Text="Populate" OnDirectClick="Populate" />
        <ext:PropertyGrid ID="PropertyGrid1" runat="server">
            <Source>
                <ext:PropertyGridParameter Name="initial" Value="property" />
            </Source>
        </ext:PropertyGrid>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PropertyGrid internally uses its own store and its unavailable to bind data to in a similar way as you can do with a GridPanel.

I think nothing stops you to use a a common GridPanel if you have such a requirement.